# Hide \thechapter for unnumbered Chapters

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I want to display my Chapter-Numbers on the right below the Title. I came to the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\LARGE\selectfont}{}{0em}{}[\marginnote{\Huge\thesection}]

\begin{document}
    \section{First section with\\linebreak}
        \lipsum[2]
    \section*{Unnumbered}
        \lipsum[12]
    \section{Three}
        \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

However the unnumbered section now gets numbered as 1. How can I suppress `\thesection` for unnumbered sections?
When I move the `\marginnote` to the `<label>` field in `\titleformat` the Number 'ignores' that the Title contains linebreaks and is positioned relative to the first line.

EDIT:
As an example, this is my code for the chapter. Using your solution – which works without an `\if` – I get the Error “`\begin{document} missing`“.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontsize{40}{10}}{}{0em}{#1}[
    \begin{textblock}{2}(13.7,3.2)
        \color[rgb]{0.39453,0.48047,0.511719}   % Error Happens Here
        \thechapter
    \end{textblock}
]
```

As soon as I add a \if around the block, the error disappears.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontsize{40}{10}}{}{0em}{#1}[
    \iftrue{
        \begin{textblock}{2}(13.7,3.2)
            \color[rgb]{0.39453,0.48047,0.511719}   % No Error Happens with if
            \thechapter
        \end{textblock}
    }
    \fi
]
```

Comment: I think I would use `\llap` instead of `\marginnote`

Comment: @cmhughes Could you give an example of using `\llap` instead of `\marginnote`? Why would you use it instead?

Comment: I just compiled your MWE- nevermind, I see that `\llap` wouldn't produce the same results, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would opt for a solution that is semantically more clear. `titlesec` provides the option to specify a different style for numberless sections.

Copy your original command, specify `numberless`, remove the things you don't want to show (like section numbers) and you're done!

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
% Regular sections:
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\LARGE\selectfont}{}{0em}{}[\marginnote{\Huge\thesection}]
% ...etc

% Numberless sections:
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{\LARGE\selectfont}{}{0em}{#1}
% ...etc
```

Comment: I just noticed a problem with your solution. As soon as I remove the `\if...\fi` around my definition (even `\iftrue` works), Latex gives me `Missing \begin{document}` at my `\color{...}` call. Any Ideas? @DavidCarlisle You might get it back, if I don't get this to work ;)

Comment: @jacob11235 there is no color of `\if` in this solution or in your original question, so it isn't clear what code you are referring to that doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the Code to the Question. The `\if` came from your answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Finally found the Problem. `\color`'s optional argument's closing Bracket was matched to `\titleformat`'s opening bracket. Adding braces around it fixed the Error.

Answer (score 7):

You can test whether the `*` version is being used by

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\LARGE\selectfont}{}{0em}{}[\if\ttl@key@numberless\marginnote{\Huge\thesection}\fi]
\makeatother
```

as  `\ttl@key@numberless` is // for numbered form so the `\if` is true as the same character appears twice, and it is `/*` for the unnumbered section so the `\if` compares `/` and `*` which are false.